# Where should I put functions that are accessed by models? -- Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I've been told that the helpers are just for functions that are needed by the views.

Where should I put in functions that are used commonly by models? What about controllers?

What's the convention to place commonly used functions that will be used in:

1) models

2) views

3) controllers

**Problem:** Creating a module in lib to hold the functions and including the module in a class would create a boat-load of instance methods for the class.

**Problem:** What about functions that are common and needed in all three?

Comment: Can you give an example of a function that would be needed in all three?

Comment: extract_domain_name(url) -- which might be used by both models and controllers for logic.

Comment: Both those examples belong in your `/lib` folder, or a specific gem. Create a module or a class that 'knows/handles everything about' urls or stemming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- for Controllers - put common methods in `application_controller.rb`
- for Views - put common methods in `application_helper.rb`
- for Models - monkeypatch `ActiveRecord::Base` to include common methods OR write a module with common model methods and include it in the models that need it OR do it in OOP way by subclassing ActiveRecord::Base with your abstract class, then inheriting all your models from this class.

To use common methods in both Model and Controller, do one of the following:

- Write a plain ruby class, put it in /lib or elsewhere, just make sure it's loaded, then `require` it when you need to use its methods.
- Extract common functionality to a gem, install it, require it when you need it. Publish it to rubygems if it's something valuable.

Comment: Thanks. What would you recommend for a function which is used in both models and controllers?

Answer (score 5):

> Problem: Creating a module in lib to hold the functions and including the module in a class would create a boat-load of instance methods for the class.

First organize, then optimize

> Problem: What about functions that are common and needed in all three?
>   Do you really have methods that are needed in all the three and not exist yet ?
>   If yes, may be you can give an exemple

I think the question should be where to put logic in general.
You should first think what your method does before to think about where to put it.
But whatever you create, when it's getting big and or valuable, you should really think about exporting it as a gem/plugin.

**Inner navigation logic (what to display and where to go after an action) : Controllers**

- App navigation logic; application_controller
- Sub set of app logic; create a namespace with master controller, class API_controller < application_controller

**Data logic (How to manipulate, process data) : Models**

- Data; Model class method (search, sorting, counting, macro process ...)
- Datum; Model instance method (modification, micro process ...)

**Data presentation logic (How to display data) : Helper, Partial and Decorators**

- Helper are not designed for that in my opinion.
- Partial handle layouting of specific data.
- application decorator; handle generic data presentation help
- scope_decoration; you can use inheritance

**Layout language logic (layout language help) : Helper**

- Specific to your app; application_helper
- Specific to a model ...; model_helper, but you should consider decorator
- Generic; export it in a gem (super form helper, templating system ...)

**Layout logic (should i display this menu ?) : ?**

- Helper/decorator/model can should answer the question : @user.can_edit?(@article)
- Layout handle the display <%= render :partial => allowed ? "something" : "somthing else" %>

I think if you are not in this configuration you are creating kind of backend system.
So it should go in lib, then in a gem later.

This organization is just an exemple. The most important thing is to organize your code and split different logic layers and don't hesitate to refactor/export code to make it generic after adding new features...

Answer (score 2):

... Usually, I put those kind of functions into common superclasses: For models, that could be (for example) Animal for subclasses Dog, Cat, etc. Within the Animal model, you would have to

```
self.abstract_class = true
```

so it doesn't expect a table for that class. For controllers, you could either use ApplicationController or you could make your controllers be derived by another common subclass.

Answer (score 2):

In the `Model` you should store all the methods that have a relation to the model itself like manipulating attributes, scopes, associating,...

In the `View` you dont store any logic! The logic belongs to the model. In the view you only put code that helps you to display stuff.

The `Controller` is the "bridge" between both. You select data in the controller, call methods that are stored in the model,... A common failure is to store the logic in the controller which should be stored in the model.

When you store a method in your `Model`you can access it from the model, the view and the controller! If you have a method that doesn't have a relation to a specific model or its needed in several models you can use the `Helper`. An example for such a case might be a method that rewrites your url using a pattern. This might be needed in 20 models to prepare a string for `to_param`. That method would be stored in an `Helper` that could be included in the Models its needed.